# Filter listview with custom layout?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, filter

So I have a basic custom listview with an image and text for each list item and I was wondering how I would filter through the listview dynamically with an edittext box. I looked up how to do it but I'm stuck at one point where I'm not sure what to do.

My listview is populated from an sqlitedatabase where I have methods that retrieve all the images names, text and ids from the database and puts them into the listview. Here is my code so far where I'm not quite sure what I should be doing in the publishResult() method

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView data;
EditText inputSearch;
ArrayList<String> names, images, ids;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
MyDatabase helper;
ImageView sprite;
TextView name, id;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    data = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    helper = new MyDatabase(this);
    helper.openDataBase();

    names = helper.getNameList();
    images = helper.getImageList();
    ids = helper.getIdList();

    adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(this);
    data.setAdapter(adapter);

    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_search);

    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
        }
    });

}

private class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    public MyArrayAdapter(Context c) {
        super(c, R.layout.item_view,names);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        if (convertView == null){
            row = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent,false);
        }

        sprite = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.sprite);
        name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);
        id = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.ids);

        name.setText(names.get(position).toString());
        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(images.get(position),"drawable", getPackageName());
        sprite.setImageResource(resID);
        id.setText(ids.get(position).toString());

        return row;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Filter(){

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence input) {

                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                int originalLength = names.size();

                if (input == null || input.length() == 0){
                    results.values = names;
                    results.count = originalLength;
                } else {
                    ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < originalLength; i++){
                        String str = names.get(i);
                        if (str.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(input))
                            newList.add(str);
                        results.values = newList;
                        results.count = newList.size();
                    }
                }
                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence,
                    FilterResults results) {

                //Not sure what to do here

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        };
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty simple at that point...

Edit:

```
public class FakeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

        public class Model {
            String my_string;
            int resource_id;
        }

        private Activity activity;

    /* ArrayList to hold the original values before filtering. */
    private ArrayList<Model> original_list;

    /* Current Data Filter */
    private Filter filter;

    public RelationshipsAdapter(Activity activity, int resource,
            ArrayList<Model> objects) {
        super(activity, resource, objects);
        this.activity = activity;
        this.original_list = objects;
    }

    /**
     * Viewholder pattern to minimize findViewById calls.
     */
    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        ImageView image;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Model currentmodel = getItem(position);

        View rowView = null;
        if(convertView == null){
            rowView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_item, parent, false);

            final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
            holder.image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
            rowView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            rowView = convertView;
        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        holder.name.setText(currentmodel.my_string);
        holder.friendship.setImageResource(currentmodel.resource_id);

        return rowView;
    };

    /**
     * Returns a filter to the calling activity to filter the underlying data set by name.
     */
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter(){
        if(filter == null){
            filter = new ModelFilter();
        }
        return filter;
    }

    /** Custom Filter implementation used to filter names alphabetically on a provided prefix. */
    private class ModelFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence search) {
            FilterResults filter_results = new FilterResults();
            String prefix = search.toString();

            /* If the search is empty, display the original dataset. */
            if(UserInputValidation.checkText(prefix).equals(StatusCode.NULL_INPUT)){
                filter_results.values = original_list;
                filter_results.count = original_list.size();
            } else {
                                //make a copy of the original items and use that array list
                final ArrayList<RelationshipModel> results = new ArrayList<RelationshipModel>(original_list);
                final ArrayList<RelationshipModel> results_holder = new ArrayList<RelationshipModel>();

                int count = results.size();
                for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
                    final RelationshipModel model = results.get(i);
                    final String name = (model.first_name + " " + model.last_name).toLowerCase(Locale.US);
                    if(name.contains(prefix))
                        results_holder.add(model);
                }
            filter_results.values = results_holder;
            filter_results.count = results_holder.size(); 
            }
            return filter_results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {
            clear();
            addAll((ArrayList<RelationshipModel>) results.values);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: That half fixes it. How do I account for images to also filter as well since the above code only filters the text and not the images.Also would I need to make another copy of my name array since if I simply clear() then addAll() to my name array, I'll lose all my original data

Comment: "(ArrayList<RelationshipModel>) results.values" This seems to give me an error. I followed the outline of your method however when i run my app, when I type a character into the edittext box it crashes and gives me a no such method error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this , I think it help you.

```
 @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence,
                        FilterResults results) {
    if(results.count==0)
    {
    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    }else
    {
    names=(ArrayList<String> names)results.values;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

  }
```

Thanks